# Can't control rotation(Three.js GLTFLoader)

Tags: javascript, three.js, gltf

**Problem**

Why can't I rotate the angle of an object？ (scene.rotation.x += 0.03;)

Camera can ,but scene object can't.

I've been looking for a long time and still can't find the answer.

**Here is the myCode：**

```
import * as THREE from 'https://unpkg.com/three@0.126.1/build/three.module.js'
import { OrbitControls } from 'https://unpkg.com/three@0.126.1/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js'
import { GLTFLoader } from 'https://unpkg.com/three@0.126.1/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js'

const canvas = document.querySelector('.fan1') // it is my class
const scene = new THREE.Scene()
var ourObj;

const loader = new GLTFLoader()
//load glb file
loader.load('assets/fan.glb', function (glb) {
    const root = glb.scene;
    root.scale.set(10,10,10)
    scene.add(root);
}, function (xhr) {  //xhr
    console.log("xhr");
}, function (error) { //error
    console.log("error");
})

const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
light.position.set(2, 2, 5);
scene.add(light);

const size = {
    width: window.innerWidth,
    height: window.innerHeight
}

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 100); 
camera.position.set(0, 1, 3);
scene.add(camera);


const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true,
    alpha: true,
    canvas: canvas
})

renderer.setClearColor("#DDDDDD");
renderer.setSize(size.width, size.height);
renderer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio, 2))
var render = function () {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    scene.rotation.x += 0.03;
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

render()
```

Control _x is invalid

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRWFT.png)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're adding the camera to the scene with `scene.add(camera);` This means that when you rotate the scene the camera *rotates with it*, so you won't notice much movement in the final render.

You don't need to add your camera to your scene. Just remove the line

```
scene.add(camera);
```

so that your camera is "free" and independent of any scene transformations.